# How to update embedded arrays/objects in MongoDb with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document

My MongoDB document looks like this:

```
  {_id: ObjectId("xxx"),  
   username: 'user',  
   active_courses: [  
        {'name': 'MongoDB',  
         'notes': [  
           {'title': 'Note title',  
            'note': 'Actual note content'}  
       ]}  
    ]
```

And now I would need to update the notes Object with title 'Note title'. How can I do this?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```js
Student.findOneAndUpdate(
  {username:req.body.username},
  {$set: {'active_courses.$[course].notes.$[note]': req.body}},
  {arrayFilters: [{'course.name': req.body.course},{'note.title': req.body.title} ]})
 .then(result => {
  res.status(200).json({message: 'Note saved!'})
 })
```

And BTW I do not know the indexes of the arrays so I can't use active_courses[0].notes...

Appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your embedded documents as a schema, this way mongoose automatically generates an objectid for them. With that id, you could access and then modify your subdocument via its parent like this:

```
var doc = parent.children.id(_id);
```

[Mongoose subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)